# Current divergence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

How do I calculate the current divergence  $$\partial_\mu A_{ud}^\mu = \partial_\mu\left (\overline{u} \gamma^\mu \gamma^5 d(x)\right )?$$

I don't understand exactly how to manipulate gamma matrices.

Comment: Show your work. Start  by writing down Dirac's equation and its conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:
$$
\partial_\mu A_{ud}^\mu =  (\partial_\mu \overline{u}(x))\gamma^\mu\gamma^5 d(x) + \overline{u}(x))(\gamma^\mu \gamma^5)(\partial_\mu d(x))\\
= (i m_u \overline{u}(x))\gamma^5d(x) + \overline{u}(x)(-\gamma^5)(-i m_d d(x)\\
= i(m_u + m_d) \overline{u}(x) \gamma^5 d(x)
$$

Comment: Looks fine: what is the problem?